# Mouse Events for objects in an array in Flash

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I am not sure how to make this clear but : Is there a way to allow mouse event register with objects in an array? I have multiple objects being added to stage from an array and i would like to call different functions after said objects are clicked on ? I have  this:

```
        function makeEnemies():void
    {
        //create humans

        var tempEnemy:MovieClip;
        var wolf:MovieClip;
        tempEnemy = new Enemy2();
        tempEnemy.cacheAsBitmap = true;
        tempEnemy.speed = 20;
        tempEnemy.x = Math.round(Math.random() * 800);
        tempEnemy.y = Math.round(Math.random() * 480);
        addChild(tempEnemy);
        enemies.push(tempEnemy);
    }

    function moveEnemies():void
    {
        var tempEnemy:MovieClip;
        for (var i:int =enemies.length-1; i>=0; i--)
        {
            tempEnemy = enemies[i];

            if (tempEnemy.x > stage.stageWidth)
            {
                tempEnemy.x = stage.stageWidth;
            }

            if (tempEnemy.y > stage.stageHeight)
            {
                tempEnemy.y = stage.stageHeight;
            }
            tempEnemy.x +=  Math.round(Math.random() * tempEnemy.speed);
            tempEnemy.y -=  Math.round(Math.random() * tempEnemy.speed);

                tempEnemy.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, scoreM);

        function scoreM(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            makeBite(tempEnemy.x, tempEnemy.y);
            removeEnemy(i);
            score++;
            score_txt.text = String(score);
        }

    function removeEnemy(idx:int)
{
    removeChild(enemies[idx]);
    enemies.splice(idx,1);
}
```

And i get an error

```
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
    at veinsVtest_fla::MainTimeline/removeEnemy()
    at MethodInfo-67()
```

Comment: i is not being carried across, you can make your own listener types where you can pass the index. Or you can cycle through the enemies array and check if the owner of event == enemies[index] then remove that one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't need an Array for this job. Like Man of Snow said. Use event.currentTarget will point to the "clicked on Enemy"

```
tempEnemy.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, scoreM);

function scoreM(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var clickedOnEnemy:MovieClip = event.currentTarget as MovieClip;

    //Now you have your enemy, do whatever you please with him.
    makeBite(clickedOnEnemy.x, clickedOnEnemy.y);

    //And farewell, my enemy ... time to remove him.
    removeChild(clickedOnEnemy);
    clickedOnEnemy = null;

    score++;
    score_txt.text = String(score);
}
```

*** EDIT ****

There are several ways to implement "removeAllEnemies". 
One way to do it is to use have another MovieClip to hold all enemies created.

So create a movieClip and add it to stage.

```
var enemiesWrapper : MovieClip = new MovieClip();
addChild(enemiesWrapper);
```

And then instead of add enemy to root

```
addChild(tempEnemy); //Instead of doing this
```

Add them to this MovieClip instead.

```
enemiesWrapper.addChild(tempEnemy);  //Do this instead
```

Note that your removeChild has to be updated accordingly

```
enemiesWrapper.removeChild(clickedOnEnemy);
```

And for "removeAllEnemies" function

```
function removeAllEnemies() {

    while(enemiesWrapper.numChildren > 0) {
        enemiesWrapper.removeChildAt(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you that works ! but now it leaves all the clips on stage unless i click on them...how do i clear up after my timer runs out?

Comment: I just edit my answer. Let me know if that works out for you, cheers! :)

Comment: **+1** @Doppy You seemed to like my answer, seems like when you *like* an answer, you *upvote* it :)

Comment: Oh ok, @ManofSnow ... Initially I intended to add a comment in your answer.... but I need 50 reputation to do that. So post new answer is the only way I could do. I do apologize if I misbehave, I am very new to this Stackoverflow. Still need to learn how to be a good member. Cheers.

Comment: @Doppy It's fine, you don't have that much REP, but others might not be so friendly to you.  You're lucky because as3 isn't a popular tag

Answer (score 1):

Replace `removeEnemy(i);` with `removeEnemy(event.currentTarget);`

You cannot remove an integer, because it isn't a child.  However, I'm assuming you want to remove the **MovieClip** that was clicked, and it looks like `removeEnemy` calls `removeChild()` on the parameter.  If not, do you mind showing your `removeEnemy` function?

Comment: Indeed i want to remove the MovieClip when clicked on and add an action as what to happens on this very occasion. removeEnemy is `function removeEnemy(idx:int)
{
 removeChild(enemies[idx]);
 enemies.splice(idx,1);
}`

Comment: you need to iterate through the array first so you don't make a failed access to an item that doesn't exist

Comment: i have added remove Enemy function on the topic

Comment: how do i do that? u mean i have to link the mouse event to array first before removing objects from it?

Comment: @ryoukos `event.currentTarget` is the object the mouse event was added to; also, show your `removeEnemy` script.  Also, the array is *fine,* you're having errors with the `removeEnemy` function